# Polymer iron-ajax data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, polymer

I'm trying to display iron-ajax data in a Highcharts gauge.

i can fetch the data and display it in the dom part and also print the data to console.

But the data doesn't get passed to highcharts.

how can i render the data do highcharts?

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="../../bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/highcharts/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>


<dom-module id="bazdara-page-trenutno">
<template>
  <style include="shared-styles">
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

<h2 class="page-title">Trenutne razmere</h2>

<div id="veter" style="width:100%;height:300px"></div>

<iron-ajax id="ajax"
url="{{url}}"
last-response="{{data}}"
handle-as="json"
debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>

{{data.veter.max}}

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
  is: 'bazdara-page-trenutno',


  properties: {
    url: {
      type: String,
      value: 'https://x.bazdara.com/trenutno.php'
    },
    data: Object
  },

  observers: [
    '_requestData(url)',
    '_chartData(data)'
  ],

  _requestData: function(url) {
    this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  },

        _chartData: function (data) {

          var gaugeOptions = {

                  chart: {
                      type: 'solidgauge',
                                    backgroundColor: null,
                  },

                  title: null,
                  credits: {
                      enabled: false
                  },
                  exporting: {
                      enabled: false
                  },

                  pane: {
                    center: ['50%', '75%'],
                    size: '150%',
                    startAngle: -90,
                    endAngle: 90,
                      background: {
                          backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                          innerRadius: '60%',
                          outerRadius: '100%',
                          shape: 'arc'
                      }
                  },

                  tooltip: {
                      enabled: false
                  },

                  // the value axis
                  yAxis: {
                      stops: [
                          [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                          [0.4, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                          [0.7, '#DF5353'] // red
                      ],
                      lineWidth: 0,
                      minorTickInterval: null,
                      tickPixelInterval: 400,
                      tickWidth: 0,
                    labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
                  },

                  plotOptions: {
                      solidgauge: {
                          dataLabels: {
                              y: 5,
                              borderWidth: 0,
                              useHTML: true
                          }
                      }
                  }
              };

              console.log(data.veter.max); // This works

              $(this.$.veter).highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
                  yAxis: {
                      min: 0,
                      max: 18.100000381469727,
                  },

                  series: [{
                      name: 'Hitrost Vetra',
                      data: [data.veter.max], // Data not displayed, if i use a number like 20 it works
                      dataLabels: {
                          enabled: false
                      },
                      tooltip: {
                          enabled: false
                      }
                  }]

              }));

        }

});
</script>
```

Comment: could you please log the argument data inside _chartData and show the results?

Comment: do you mean the whole json response?

Comment: _chartData: function (data) {console.log(data) .....

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ubzgTKJv

Comment: could be that my json is malformed?
you can view it directly here: https://x.bazdara.com/trenutno.php

Comment: It can be a problem with load data later then you init the chart. In other words the chart should be initialised in the ajax callback (success).

Comment: i did try wraping the highcharts part in setTimeout(function() { .. }, 5000);
 .. for a quick test ... but it didnt help